# How to use array inside while loop so it can track every id fetching from database?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm fetching multiple rows from a database. That's why  I use a `while` loop but I need every individual ID inside the `while` loop. How can I use an array inside the while loop?
The `friendid` just prints the last result from the loop.I don't want to print the result inside the loop.

```
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql))
   {
     $name = $row['name'];
     $friendid = $row['id'];  
   }
    echo $friendid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty array before the `while` loop. In each iteration of the loop, append the fetched row to *this* array.

```
$resultArr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql)){
    $resultArr[] = array($row['id'], $row['name']);
}
// display $resultArr array
var_dump($resultArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$ids = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql))
   {
     $name = $row['name'];
     $ids[] = $row['id'];  
   }
   print_r($ids);
```

Comment: Welcome! Please accept as correct answer and vote up it. Thank you

Comment: Actually credit goes to @Rajdeep Paul. He was the first. Sorry next time